# Derivative of a definite improper integral

Tags: definite-integrals, singularity-theory, taylor-expansion

-The derivative with respect to beta, for the following definite integral is required.

g = $\int_\beta^{\sqrt(\beta^2 +1}$ $erfc(\gamma z)/\sqrt(z^2 - \beta^2)$dz

-I am using the leibniz formula given here: 
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeibnizIntegralRule.html

-To calculate the leibniz integral I need the function value at the lower limit which is beta. The function has a singularity at this value.

-My idea was to use a taylor series expansion for approximating the limiting value of the function at beta. **Is that a correct approach?**

Question: Is there any other way this could be done and if this approach of calculating the derivative of the integral using the leibniz formula correct at all?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Leibniz formula is correct. You could also split the intergral into three pieces from $b$ to $\sqrt{\beta^2+1}$, from $a$ to $b$ and from $\beta$ to $a$. Then the only additional things you need are the fundamental theorem of calculus and the chain rule.

Comment: Thanks, I don't exactly understand what you mean. I guess the limits are not a problem. In the leibniz formula the function must be evaluated at beta and at that point the function value is infinite as erfc term is finite. I want a way to deal with that term. My idea is to use a taylor series.